# Is it possible to autoscroll by setting the contentOffset?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have one scrollview that contain about 11 images and the scrollView will show only one image on screen. I need to make it autoscroll image by image. I did something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:120
                      delay:1
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{        
                     self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x+172*11,0);

                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

the scrollview scroll through all the width its has and i can see the connection between the image. Is it possible to autoscroll by setting the contentOffset?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354360/how-to-add-auto-scroll-functionality-to-a-view-in-iphone-sdk please find this link..hope it helps

Comment: I think it would be easier to use 'setContentOffset:animated' message of the 'UIScrollView' (with a timer) instead of an animation block. See bhanu's solution, I haven't tried it but it seems good.

Comment: You can use also UIPageControl and use "self.pageControl.currentPage = page" by timer.

Answer (score 5):

I made my UIScrollView Auto Scroll by set contentOffset like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.0 target:self selector:@selector(loadUrl) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void) loadUrl
{
    currentOffset = scrlFirstScroll.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat newOffset = currentOffset + 3;
    [scrlFirstScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0,newOffset) animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: i try it and it just scroll only first image to second, i'm new to this , i don't know how to make it scroll image by image to the last image.Can you tell me?